# Are php statements executed synchronously?

Tags: php

Ok this seems like a stupid question that I should certainly know the answer to, but I've got some weird behavior where the constructor of one of my classes checks to see if a table exists, if not it creates it.

The strange thing is when the table doesn't exist, if the constructor is called multiple times then it doesn't see the table that should have been created on the first constructor call.

**Are all function calls synchronous in PHP?**

For example:

```
f1();
f2();
```

Does the interpreter wait for `f1()` to return before calling `f2()`?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to `COMMIT` after creating the table?

Comment: I'm not using transactions - and the table creation works, it just appears to not work for the first few constructor calls. Subsequent requests detect the presence of the table correctly, it is just the first time running the script the constructor is called several times and the first time it correctly finds no table and creates it but the next calls it doesn't see the table that has just been created and tries to re-create it....

Comment: That's... strange. I recommend asking on DBA.SE.

Comment: thanks - I'll have a another go at investigating and then post on DBA. It could be that mysql's internal cache isn't committed instantly but that seems unlikely since that would break ACID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the interpreter wait for `f1()` to return before calling `f2()`?

Yes, even if `f1()` kicks off other asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Thank! I kind of knew the answer had to be yes - a procedure that depended on order of execution would work otherwise... I just can't figure out why I'm getting the behavior that I am...

Comment: @rgvcorley the constructor could not be called more than one times for any case , may be you are initiation the object multiple times or any hidden trigger does that.

Comment: @RupeshPatel correct - every time you create an object, the constructor is called ;)

Comment: @rgvcorley so my point was if you see the constructor called multiple times than check for multiple object initializations in you code

Comment: @Rupesh: His point is that he is *deliberately* instantiating a class multiple times, and work done in previous instantiations doesn't appear to have taken place.